# Как убрать фон у родителя jquery

Tags: jquery

Помогите пожалуста при разработке кода  надо при клике на LUX убрать фон с con_map вот код
HTML

```
<div id="con_map">
 <div class="link lux">LUX
   <div class="child">text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#con_map {
    background-image:url('img/myimg.png');}
```

jqwery

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  $('> .child', $(this)).show(); 
    $('#con_map').css("background-image:none");});
```

элемент child появляеться а background-image у con_map не уходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#con_map').css("background-image","none");
```

Comment: А можно у знать как закрыть вопрос ?

Comment: @Sergalas это не обязательно. не обращайте внимания.

Comment: Ну так все же культурнее (и награду дают) :)

Comment: не знаю про какую награду вы говорите, но закрывают вопрос обычно если это спам или пошел флейм или флуд. в остальных случаях это не обязательно, вдруг кто-то еще захочет что-либо написать (не в этом конкретном вопрос, а вообще). У модераторов есть привилегия закрытия вопросов, если они посчитают, что вопрос нужно закрыть, закроют. )